# How can I run a program on computer startup?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# MVC program that I want to run when the computer starts regardless if a user has signed in or not. The program will be running on Windows 7 & Windows 10 machines. This is the code I have written but I'm not sure if it's working correctly. This code runs if a checkbox is selected:

```
private void runOnStartup_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.startup = true;          
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    registryKey.SetValue("MyProgram", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());



    WshShell wshShell = new WshShell();
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut;
    string startUpFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
    shortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(startUpFolderPath + "\\Shortcutpath.something");
    shortcut.TargetPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; 
    shortcut.Description = "My program";
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

If this isn't the proper way to get an application to run as soon as the machine starts, please let me know and I can change the code.

EDIT: I should have noted that this is a WPF application, with an interface.

Comment: What type of program is this actually? Based on the method signature it doesn't look like asp.net MVC at all. Are you trying to run your program as a Windows Service?

Comment: Also, I thoroughly disagree with whoever VTC as "general computing hardware and software".

Comment: I suspect this is a WPF app, going by `RoutedEventArgs`.

Comment: couldn't understand your question but if you want something running in the background i would say, that the best option is a windows service.

Comment: According to [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys): _Run and RunOnce registry keys cause programs to run each time that a user **logs on**_.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "correctly"? What is the current outcome and how does it differ from your expected outcome?

Comment: Sorry, I confused the type of project this is. This is a WPF application with an interface.

Comment: I don't understand what it means to have a programming running with a **user interface** but no user signed in. The whole idea of a user interface is that there is a user, you know, **using** it. Can you explain? It sounds like you are trying to do something very wrong.

Comment: This program is a device poller. The user sets how often the program checks on devices on the network, give credentials to a database, operates with the database, starts and stops the poller, etc. I need the polling part of the program, that doesn't interact with the user, to start when the machine starts.

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do. As noted above, literally starting a program with the computer boots doesn't make sense if the program has a UI, like a WPF program. So maybe you're just looking for the "Startup" folder, which has programs to run when the user logs in (see third marked duplicate). Alternatively, maybe you want a service to run, allowing it to run immediately on computer startup, and then write a _separate_ WPF program that interacts with that service, to provide a UI to a user, once the user has logged in. See first two duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a [...] program that I want to run when the computer starts regardless if a user has signed in or not.

That is called a Windows Service. There are multiple ways to write one, you can use C# for it. Find a good tutorial, book or other explanation and write one. You may want to split your program in different assemblies, to have a part where your program logic resides that can be used in your UI *and* the service and then a Windows Service and whatever you have now as a UI.

I have heard good things about [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/), but a plain Windows Service [as explained by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) might be sufficient.

Comment: _"you ask a broad question, you get a broad answer"_

Comment: Just as an aside, Topshelf is a fantastic framework that makes developing services a breeze.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My program is a C# WPF application. Will a Windows Service interface with the program, even if it has a GUI?